# Segue Error with UITextField Text Inset

Tags: ios, swift, text, view, uitextfield

I am currently segueing to a view controller with the following code in the view did load (firstTf and secondTF are IBOutlets that work properly):

```
let spacerView = UIView(frame:CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:10, height:firstTF.frame.height))
firstTF.leftView = spacerView
firstTF.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
secondTF.leftView = spacerView
secondTF.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
```

When I run the program, the segue never occurs and the app just pauses. When I comment this code out, everything runs smoothly. All I am trying to do is inset the text of these two textfields. What am I doing wrong?

Note: no error is given when the code is left, but the app pauses and becomes unresponsive

Comment: Try creating 2 spacers instead of only 1. A single view should not have 2 different parent.

Comment: Can you able to share more code?

Comment: What is the `spacerView` and how it is created and most importantly, sized?

Comment: try using a different `UIView` for every `UITextField`